# how to tokenize a list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tokenize

I have an excel file, which has different columns.

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

I want to get the text columns in df object and tokenize each word seperately in the list.

```
text = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    text.append(df.text[i])     


text.split()
```

I try split function for tokenization but received;

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.
```

How can I overcome this issue ?

Comment: why are you using `text.split()`? lists (like `text`) are already split into elements. maybe try `print text` and tell us how that is different than what you expect?

Comment: ok, after appending df.text[i] into text list; the result is:           ['@Cem44__',  'Kimse bizim milli  kaldıramaz !',  'En kısa sürede bu yanlışın düzeltilmesini istiyoruz.…', 'everything is fine.', ... ]       text[1] is 'Kimse bizim milli  kaldıramaz !'. I want to get each word as a  seperated list item such as ['Kimse', 'bizim', 'milli', 'kaldıramaz', '!']

Comment: ok, then you probably want to `split()` the `string` before you append it to the list: `text.append(df.text[i].split())`

Comment: but this way makes lists in a list. I want to get all text items as a one list.

Comment: ok sorry about that, instead try `text.extend(df.text[i].split())`

Comment: that solves my problem. Thank you @downshift